# How to rewind/fast-forward audio messages in iOS

Tags: messages, ios

Is it just me or is there really no way to rewind or fast-forward audio messages received with the Messages app (iMessage)? I have iOS 13 on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way (tested on iOS13).

1. Long press on the audio in Messages, a pop up will appear with 3 options: "Copy", "Save" and "More..."
2. Choose "Copy"
3. Switch to the Files app and go a folder of your choosing (I chose a folder under "On my iPhone")
4. Long press and chose "Paste"
5. Open as audio file, where you can scrub, pause, fast-forward, etc.

Comment: @altineoSE Your solution is working, but it is very convoluted. I wish able would give us an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Works well and only takes a couple extra seconds.

Answer (score 1):

1. Long press on the audio message and then tap on the large waveform symbol to "open" the audio message.
2. To seek, swipe left-right using 1 finger on the waveform track at the bottom.